# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 13 Appendix "Riemann Sums, Problem 3: Prove formula for length of parametric curve based on inscribed polygonal curve.

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

The following is a problem from the appendix to Chapter 13 entitled "Riemann Sums", from Spivak's Calculus

> 3 . Consider a curve $c$ given parametrically by two functions $u$ and $v$ on $[a,b]$. For a partition $P=\{t_0,...,t_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ we
> define
>
> $$l(c,P)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n
>  \sqrt{[u(t_i)-u(t_{i-1})]^2+[v(t_i)-v(t_{i-1})]^2}$$
>
> this represents the length of an inscribed polygonal curve. We define the length of $c$ to be the least upper bound of
> all $l(f,P)$, if it exists.
>
> Prove that if $u'$ and $v'$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, then the length
> of $c$ is
>
> $$\int\limits_a^b \sqrt{u'^2+v'^2}$$

[image]

My question is about the sentence

> We define the length of $c$ to be the least upper bound of all
> $l(f,P)$, if it exists.

Why does the problem statement mention $l(f,P)$, ie why the function $f$ instead of $c$?

I would have expected the length of $c$ to be the least upper bound of $l(c,P)$ for all possible partitions $P$.

Comment: This is a typo. Even the most carefully written books have misprints/typos. Just use common sense.

Comment: Common sense on the part of a novice reader of a book like this can lead to errors. I prefer to make sure. Many times what I thought was a typo was actually something I was missing.

Comment: If an $f$ appeared somewhere, I would be inclined to agree with you. However, ....